# How to expose an HTTPS endpoint with strimzi-kafka-bridge?

Tags: apache-kafka, strimzi

I am able to set up the bridge and connect to an existing Kafka cluster and read data using HTTP requests. Is there a way to add a layer of security and expose an HTTPS endpoint for fetching Kafka records instead of plain HTTP?

I have a certificate and private key, where should I add these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The strimzi HTTP bridge does not currently support HTTPS. You can put a reverse proxy (e.g. nginx) in front of it to do HTTPS and forward requests over HTTP to the bridge.